# Running LLC from rust results in undefined reference to `main' for linking with gcc

Tags: rust, llvm

Consider the hello world in LLVM-IR

```
@.str = internal constant [14 x i8] c"hello, world\0A\00"
declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) nounwind {
entry:
  %tmp1 = getelementptr [14 x i8], [14 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0
  %tmp2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf( i8* %tmp1 ) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}
```

When I nor launch a `llc` process from rust:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
fn main() {
    Command::new("/usr/lib/llvm-8/bin/llc")
        .env_clear()
        .arg("test.bc")
        .arg("-o")
        .arg("test.s")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
}
```

I can not link the resulting `test.s` with gcc `gcc test.s -no-pie -o test`:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function `_start':
>
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But when I ran `llc` direct in the terminal:

```sh
env -i /usr/lib/llvm-8/bin/llc test.bc -o test.s
```

Everything works well.

Does someone know some details?

Comment: Did you try adding "-filetype=asm" as an argument to the command?

Comment: @FrankC.Yes, but this does not change anything.